# prevent to crash node js after uncaughtExceptions

Tags: node.js

i have written one middle-ware for handling uncaughtExceptions which is working fine but after that server will crashed.
how do i prevent to crash it?

**server.js:**

```
const express = require('express');
const winston = require("winston");
const app = express();

//Logging is responsible to log and display errors
require('./startup/logging')();
//routes will contains all the routes list
require('./startup/routes')(app);

//PORT
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port,() => winston.info(`Listening on port ${port}....`));
```

**logging.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const winston = require('winston');
// require('express-async-errors');

module.exports = function() {
  winston.handleExceptions(
    new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'uncaughtExceptions.log' })
  );

  process.on('unhandledRejection', (ex) => {
    throw ex;
  });

  winston.add(winston.transports.File, { filename: 'error.log' });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do `throw ex;` The program will crash, Rather you should send the crash report and message to the respective reporting mechanism that you are using. Heres a small snippet

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, promise) => {
  console.log('Unhandled Rejection at:', reason.stack || reason)
  // Recommended: send the information to sentry.io
  // or whatever crash reporting service you use
})
```